# How to use pyOCD, or open OCD from Python

Tags: python, gdb, stm32, openocd

I want to use `pyOCD` (or open OCD) for some operation with `STLink` and `STM32` MCU. I found this list of commands https://pyocd.io/docs/command_reference.html#find but I am not wise from that - I really do not understand the syntaxes.

E.G.
I want to load *.bin* file to the mem on specific address:
Documentation says: *load  FILENAME [ADDR]* ....So I wrote to the console: ***pyocd load myBin.bin 0x8005000*** but it does not work - it ignores the addr - it probably flashs the bin file but not on my desired addr.

Basicly I want to write 6 function in python:

1. check if some ST link is connected to PC (windows)
2. check if some MCU is connected to the STlink
3. erase connected MCU
4. load .bin file to the MCU
5. be able to read and write specific values to specific addres to the MCU
6. reset MCU

Would be great to use it like python library, but I absolutelly do not know how to use it, so I will settle for the command line - using subprocess in python

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have a working setup using Python for most of your desired task. For most parts there are different ways to archive it:

**1) Use subprocesses and STM32_Programmer_CLI**
Step 1-4 and 6 are possible directly with the tool from STM32. I use this code snippet to check if a device is connected or not (in this case a STM32G0). When a device is available it is possible to connect to it and read its UID which I then parse. Using the stdout it would also be possible to check if a debugger is available or not. Step 5 of your list is also possible if your are talking about static values from flash like in the example. If you need live values it gets more complicated.

```py
def read_uid():
    # STM32_Programmer_CLI -c port=SWD mode=HOTPLUG -r32 0x1FFF7590 12
    uid = ''
    cmd = ["STM32_Programmer_CLI", "-c port=SWD mode=HOTPLUG -r32 0x1FFF7590 12"]
    with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
        for line in proc.stdout:
            data = line.strip().decode().split()
            if data:
                if data[0] == '0x1FFF7590':
                    uid = ''.join(data[2::])
    stm32_uid.stm32uid = uid
    return uid
```

**2) Use OpenOCD and telnet**
For more complex use cases or reading live values during debugging I use a combination of OpenOCD and a telnet connection. I wasn't able to get pyOCD or the main OpenOCD running with the STM32 (maybe just because of configuration issues) but solved it with the [STMicroelectronics fork of OpenOCD](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/OpenOCD). It is delivered together with STM32CubeIDE and available as debugger in the *"run->debug configuration"* settings. The very helpful thing about it is that you can see the commandline options used for starting the debugger and reuse the created configuration file for your project.

With this you can start OpenOCD as a subprocess and then connect to it via telnet:

```py
import subprocess
import telnetlib

debugger = subprocess.Popen([r"stm32cube_openocd_win32\tools\bin\openocd.exe",
      "-f", r"utilities\OpenOCD_config.cfg",
      "-s", r"utilities\stm32cube_openocd_win32\resources\openocd\st_scripts",
      "-c", "telnet_port 4444"])
tel = telnetlib.Telnet('localhost', 4444)


def read_data():
    return tel.read_until(b"\r\n", 1.0)


def cmd(command):
    tel.write((f"{command}\r\n").encode())
    return read_data()


try:
    cmd("reset run")
    print(read_data().decode())
    print(cmd('mdw 0x1FFF7590 3'))
    print(read_data().decode())
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

tel.close()
debugger.terminate()
```

The configuration file and the `st_scripts` are from the STM32CubeIDE installation. The scripts are stored in the `plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.debug.openocd_XXX` folder.